# ADF TreeTable: Tree Table refreshes twice

Tags: oracle-adf

I fetching some accounts and showing on TreeTable (ADF), accounts have hyperlink on click of which popup opens. When number of accounts is too much (e.g 200) and we scroll down to bottom of the treetable , on clicking account hyperlink treetable refreshes twice due to which popup doesn't open . Can somebody help me with it

Comment: <af:treeTable value="#{bindings.VO2.treeModel}" var="node" styleClass="opTable"
                        selectionListener="#{bindings.VO2.treeModel.makeCurrent}"
                        rowSelection="single" id="tt1" fetchSize="-1"
                        inlineStyle="background-color:White; height:247px; width:916px;"
                        binding="#{backingBeanScope.AdvMgmtBean.opTreeTbl}"
                       rendered="#{pageFlowScope.viewType eq 'Month'}">

Comment: I have put a partial trigger of hyperlink on treetable as well. Any Idea what can be the issue. It only occurs when i have too many data not for less data , say 40-50

Comment: Try to change ChangeEventPolicy on list binding from PPR (default) to NONE.